# retrieving an image from parse database

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview, data-retrieval

I have my information posted already on parse database but i want to retrieve it using recircularView.
can anyone please guide me or direct me on how should i do it?

here is my code of the xml that holds the layout of the recircularView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_byte"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_word"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size_word"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_byte">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/adPic"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/movie_thumbnail_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/movie_thumbnail_height"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"

    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/adTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/adPic"
    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
    android:alpha="0.87"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="@dimen/size_half_byte"
    android:text="Hitman Agent 47"
    android:textSize="@dimen/size_text_primary" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/adPrice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/adTitle"
    android:alpha="0.87"
    android:padding="@dimen/size_half_byte"
    android:text="5.00$"
    android:textSize="@dimen/size_text_secondary" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/adDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/adPrice"
    android:alpha="0.87"
    android:padding="@dimen/size_half_byte"
    android:text="31-31-31"
    android:textSize="@dimen/size_text_secondary" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Retrieving the image has nothing to do with RecyclerView.

Comment: yeah sorry, the code posted below was before you posted your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image url from ParseObject using getUrl() method of ParseFile

Suppose you get a list of ParseObjects like this

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = nee ArrayList();
List<ParseObject> objects

for (ParseObject objectItem: objects) {
                String fileName = "";
                String fileURL = "";
                if (objectItem.getParseFile("imageColumn") != null) {
                    try {
                        ParseFile parseFile = (ParseFile) objectItem
                                .getParseFile("imageColumn");
                        fileURL = parseFile.getUrl();
                        fileName = parseFile.getName();
                        myObjects.add(new MyObject(fileName,fileURL));

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
         }
```

Later in your getView use the file URL to get the image only for the visible items in the listview. Such that your listview wont crash.

Comment: do i need to use ArrayList? cant i just get the information of each ad in parseObject and put it in the recyclerview?

Comment: why not , Its your wish..:)

Comment: if you can do it, can you show me and update your answer so i can accept it please.